# running a command in recovery then rebooting back into recovery

Tags: recovery-mode

Is there a way to run a command in recovery (that changes something in recovery)
then reboot back directly into recovery ( now with the change I made)

**Note that this is not a duplicate as I am NOT asking how to exit from recovery, but how to reboot from recovery right back to recovery - none of the answers I found in the site provide me with this option**

Results I found:

- [Running a command in screen daemon mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610017/running-a-command-in-screen-daemon-mode?s=1%7C4.4182)
- [Installing Software in recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361990/installing-software-in-recovery-mode?s=1%7C4.4261)
- [Running a command in a new terminal instance in a bash script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421136/running-a-command-in-a-new-terminal-instance-in-a-bash-script?s=1%7C3.4262)
- [Can't log into my session even in recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634120/cant-log-into-my-session-even-in-recovery-mode?s=1%7C4.1924)
- [How to Enter into Recovery mode? [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226134/how-to-enter-into-recovery-mode?s=1%7C4.6798)
- [No root account, can't boot into recovery [closed]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486361/no-root-account-cant-boot-into-recovery?s=1%7C4.1100)

Thanks in advance